# SQL to find the match record based on the priority defined

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have to build a logic to update one column `SC_LEVI_LVL IN GCC_MAST.CLNT_MAST` based on the match found on the below criteria:

(I am just looking at the select clause and I will update it later using update strategy in informatica)

The Joins needs to be made on three tables:

for Priority 1 the join needs to be made on below two tables:

```
GCC_LANDING.CB_AT_LIS CB
    GCC_MAST.CLNT_MAST TM
```

For Priority 2 the join needs to be made on below 3 tables:

```
GCC_LANDING.CB_AT_LIS CB
GCC_MAST.CLNT_MAST TM
GCC_LANDING.GRID_MATRIX GM
```

PRIORITY 1:

```
CB.REL_COUNTRY=TM.REL_COUNTRY
AND CB.GRID=TM.GRID
WHERE TM.SCH_LEG_ENTY NOT LIKE '%BASE%'
AND CB.LAT='Y'
```

Expected result:
[image]

PRIORITY 2:

```
CB.GRID=GM.GRID
AND CB.REL_COUNTRY=TM.REL_COUNTRY
AND GM.SUR_GRD=TM.GRID
WHERE TM.SCH_LEG_ENTY NOT LIKE '%BASE%'
AND TM.CUS LIKE '% BGM%'
AND CB.GRID <> TM.GRID
AND TM.CUST_FLG='N'
```

Expected results:
[image]

(IF MULTIPLE RECORDS FOUND PARTITION BY ROW_NUMBER=1)

All i can think of is putting all of them in a single query with the Joins on all tables ( combining P1 and P2) and then a case statement in the beginning. But, I don't think that will be the correct approach.

Can someone guide me to the approach on how can i proceed? I am pretty new to this and will update the post with whatever i come up with.

Desired result should be the value of SC_LEVI_LVL IN GCC_MAST.CLNT_MAST based on P1 first and if no match for P1 then for P2

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai-- At the moment I cant provide you the data. But let me try. I am looking for a construct/approach on this.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai-- added data and expected results. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone please help with the approach atleast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- here is the combination of the two - priority_one and priority_two
WITH
    landing As
        (
            Select 'NZ' "REL_COUNTRY", 12345 "GRID", 'Y' "LAT", 'ABC' "SC_LEVI_LVL" From Dual
          UNION
            Select 'MO' "REL_COUNTRY", 44444 "GRID", 'Y' "LAT", 'XYZ' "SC_LEVI_LVL" From Dual
          UNION
            Select 'PH' "REL_COUNTRY", 55555 "GRID", 'Y' "LAT", 'ERT' "SC_LEVI_LVL" From Dual
          UNION
            Select 'PH' "REL_COUNTRY", 78786 "GRID", 'Y' "LAT", 'ERT' "SC_LEVI_LVL" From Dual
        ),
    clnt As
        (
            Select 'ZA' "REL_COUNTRY", 56565 "GRID", 'HBASEU' "SCH_LEG_ENTY", 'TFGD' "CUS", 'N' "CUST_FLG" From Dual
          UNION
            Select 'NZ' "REL_COUNTRY", 12345 "GRID", 'DFGT' "SCH_LEG_ENTY", 'HBGM' "CUS", 'N' "CUST_FLG" From Dual
          UNION
            Select 'MO' "REL_COUNTRY", 44444 "GRID", 'DFGTU' "SCH_LEG_ENTY", 'HBGM' "CUS", 'N' "CUST_FLG" From Dual
          UNION
            Select 'PH' "REL_COUNTRY", 99999 "GRID", 'DFGTU' "SCH_LEG_ENTY", 'HBGM' "CUS", 'N' "CUST_FLG" From Dual
        ),
    matrix As
        ( Select 99999 "SUR_GRID", 78786 "GRID" From Dual ),
    priority_one As 
        (
            SELECT
                'ONE' "WHICH_ONE",
                cb.REL_COUNTRY "REL_COUNTRY",
                cb.GRID "GRID",
                cb.LAT "LAT",
                cb.SC_LEVI_LVL "SC_LEVI_LVL"
            FROM
                landing cb
            INNER JOIN
                clnt tm ON(CB.REL_COUNTRY=TM.REL_COUNTRY And cb.GRID = tm.GRID)
            WHERE 
                tm.SCH_LEG_ENTY NOT LIKE '%BASE%' And 
                CB.LAT = 'Y'
        ),
    priority_two As
        (
            SELECT
                'TWO' "WHICH_ONE",
                cb.REL_COUNTRY "REL_COUNTRY",
                cb.GRID "GRID",
                cb.LAT "LAT",
                cb.SC_LEVI_LVL "SC_LEVI_LVL"
            FROM
                matrix gm
            INNER JOIN
                landing cb ON(cb.GRID = gm.GRID)
            INNER JOIN
                clnt tm ON(cb.REL_COUNTRY = tm.REL_COUNTRY And gm.SUR_GRID = tm.GRID)
            WHERE 
                tm.SCH_LEG_ENTY NOT LIKE '%BASE%' And 
                cb.GRID <> tm.GRID And 
                tm.CUST_FLG = 'N'
        )
    SELECT WHICH_ONE, REL_COUNTRY, GRID, LAT, SC_LEVI_LVL From priority_one 
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT WHICH_ONE, REL_COUNTRY, GRID, LAT, SC_LEVI_LVL FROM priority_two
--
-- Result:
--
-- WHICH_ONE REL_COUNTRY       GRID LAT SC_LEVI_LVL
-- ONE       MO               44444 Y   XYZ       
-- ONE       NZ               12345 Y   ABC       
-- TWO       PH               78786 Y   ERT
```

Comment: Hi d r-- One question, will this work as a single query. I mean first priority one will be checked and if no data then P2 should get the data?

Comment: You can play with the result sets of the two querys any way you want. Yes, you can combine them further. I don't understand completely what you need but it is not a problem to make a conclusion combining those two result sets. Regards...

Comment: I want the SC_LEVI_LVL firstly from the P1 , if P1 doesn't give me anything the I need check for P2. How can I combine them further? Union? I can write two separate select queries and get the results but my problem i need to follow a priority here.

Comment: Now you have combination of the two with a remark which one is from priority one or two so you  can make a selection of them for your update. Regards...

Comment: As you can see the result set has two records from P1 and one record from P2... So SELECT whatever you need FROM (above sql in brackets) WHERE condition of your choice...

Comment: Thanks d r, Let me run the same and confirm back to you!!